# date.isValid is not a function

Tags: angular, web, ng-bootstrap

When I use the angular4 to build a website, I need to use a *ng-bootstrap* component as a datepicker, but I got a problem:
and here is my code:
what is wrong with my code!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JhiLanguageService } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { Principal, AccountService, JhiLanguageHelper } from 'app/core';
import { SettingsService } from 'app/account/settings/settings.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgbDateStruct, NgbDateAdapter, NgbDate, NgbCalendar} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Moment } from "moment";
import { User} from "app/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-settings',
    templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['settings.css']
})
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
    error: string;
    success: string;
    settingsAccount: any;
    languages: any[];
    genders: [];
    levels: [];
    avatarFileName: string;
    avatarFile: File;

    mydob= {year: 2018, month: 9, day: 15};

    constructor(
        private account: AccountService,
        private principal: Principal,
        private languageService: JhiLanguageService,
        private languageHelper: JhiLanguageHelper,
        private settingService: SettingsService,
        private today : NgbCalendar
    ) { }
}
```

Date of
                    birth

Comment: here are my errors :ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: date.isValid is not a function
TypeError: date.isValid is not a function
    at NgbDateMomentAdapter.fromModel (datepicker-adapter.ts?3e8e:12)
    at NgbInputDatepicker.writeValue (ng-bootstrap.js?e06c:3747)
    at eval (forms.js?8087:1706)
    at eval (forms.js?8087:2762)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormControl.setValue (forms.js?8087:2762)
    at eval (forms.js?8087:4115)

Comment: and my html declare:         <input class="form-control dob" placeholder="enter your birth" name="dob" id="dob" readonly
                           (click)="d.toggle()" [maxDate]="{year: 2018, month: 9, day : 13}" [minDate]="{year: 1990, month: 1, day : 1}"
                           required  name="dob" [(ngModel)]="mydob" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
                </div>

Comment: I think you should add these to the question itself.

Comment: sorry, I am a newer of stackoverflow, this is my first time use it....so I will pay attention next time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to import moment as below :

```
import * as moment from "moment";
```

After it set `mydob`, `maxDate` and `minDate` value as below in your component :

```
minDate = moment({year: 1990, month: 1, day : 1});
maxDate = moment({year: 2018, month: 9, day : 13});
mydob = moment({year: 2018, month: 9, day: 15});
```

And use below HTML input :

```
<input class="form-control dob" placeholder="enter your birth" name="dob" id="dob" readonly (click)="d.toggle()" [maxDate]="maxDate" [minDate]="minDate" required name="dob" [(ngModel)]="mydob" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
```